# Nested category query in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I need to make this operation with one query if possible.
In my products schema I have defined a many-to-many relation with categories so I have something like this

```
  categories: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'}]
```

Categories can have sub-categories so I have this in my category schema

```
  parent: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category', default:null}
```

I want to make a query to get products inside a category and all sub categories underneath it and I only have the parent category id.

This is what I have right now but I would like to have one query instead

```
var findProductsByCategories = function (ids) {

    var promise = Product.find({categories: {$in: ids}}).exec();

    promise.then(function (products) {

        res.send(products);
    });
}

// Get this category children
var promise = Category.find({parent: req.params.category}).select('_id').exec();

promise.then(function (children_ids) {

    // Add the parent id as well
    children_ids.push(req.params.category);

    return children_ids;

}).then(findProductsByCategories);
```